# Привязка линии к объекту

Tags: c#, wpf

Я постороил линию между двумя объектами.

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="ic_EdgeLine" Grid.Column="1" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Line X1="{Binding A.PosOfEllipse.X }" Y1="{Binding A.PosOfEllipse.Y }" X2="{Binding B.PosOfEllipse.X }" Y2="{Binding B.PosOfEllipse.Y}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Вот процесс создания

```
private void BtEl1_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {

     var p = sender as Ellipse;
     posOfEl = p.TransformToVisual(ic_canvas).Transform(new Point(p.ActualHeight / 2, p.ActualWidth / 2));
     output = new EllipseOfElement { ellipseOfUC = p, PosOfEllipse = posOfEl };

     connect = new EdgeLine { A = input, B = output };
     Edgeln.Add(connect);


  }

  private void ResEl1_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {

     var p = sender as Ellipse;
     posOfEl = p.TransformToVisual(ic_canvas).Transform(new Point(p.ActualHeight / 2, p.ActualWidth / 2));
     input = new EllipseOfElement { ellipseOfUC = p, PosOfEllipse = posOfEl };


  }
```

А теперь вопрос главный. Как сделать, что бы линия "прилипла" к объектам, которых соединяет. Помогите хотя бы идеей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Идеи: 1) разместить элементы на канвасе 2) Если ближайшая точка привязки к позиции мыши во время перетаскивания на расстоянии, например, 10 попугаев, то смещать конец перетаскиваемой линии туда

Comment: @tym32167 элементы на канвасе, а вот о втором подробнее можно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я завел коллекцию случайных точек, у вас они уже есть, можете просто сложить их в коллекцию:

```
Points = new List<Point>
{
    new Point(60, 150),
    new Point(180, 20),
    new Point(300, 60),
    new Point(350, 120),
    new Point(20, 90),
    new Point(120, 50),
    new Point(330, 20),
    new Point(310, 180)
};
```

При перемещении мыши выбираем ближайшую точку и проверяем расстояние, если оно меньше 30, то берем эту точку, иначе просто текущие координаты мыши:

```
private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    double Sqr(double x) => x * x;
    double Distance(Point p1, Point p2) => Math.Sqrt(Sqr(p1.X - p2.X) + Sqr(p1.Y - p2.Y));
    var coords = e.GetPosition((FrameworkElement)sender);
    var nearbyPoint = Points.OrderBy(p => Distance(p, coords)).First();
    if (Distance(nearbyPoint, coords) < 30.0) coords = nearbyPoint;
    MyLine.X2 = coords.X;
    MyLine.Y2 = coords.Y;
}
```

Разметка:

```
<Grid MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove" Background="Transparent">
    <ItemsControl Name="MyItemsControl">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse Width="4" Height="4" Fill="DarkGreen">
                    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="-2" Y="-2"/>
                    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                </Ellipse>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <Line Name="MyLine" Stroke="Black"
          X1="10" Y1="10" X2="100" Y2="100"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а алгоритм поиска дистанции как называется? Мне для образования

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Если функцию `Distance`, то это просто расстояние между двумя точками на плоскости.

Comment: Ага, оно. Спасибо